# How to install SecureSocial Module in Play 2.0 framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework and i need some help in the installation of the SecureSocail module in play2.0  as i want to make the url as " Https "  .  Or can you guys suggest me with any other possibilities ?

Answer (score 5):

The status has changed. SecureSocial is now supported for Play 2.0. See the [GitHub](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial) site

Answer (score 1):

SecureSocial is not available on Play 2.0.

In fact it's going to be really hard to get any authentication module delivered until the Team fixes routing between module and projects.

Since everything is compiled in Play 2.0, it is not possible for a module to reference the route file in your project.

Comment: Play was always statically typed.  So can you provide citation for "Since everything is compiled in Play 2.0, it is not possible for a module to reference the route file in your project."

Comment: not true, in Play1:routes were not compiled & the templates were interpreted.In 2,routes is the most critical. Since it is compiled, you cannot have your module ref imaginary routes (like you would expect).

Comment: Hello olivier  thanks for the information and so what could be the alternative of this as i cannot down grade my play version and if i have to use secure social.

Comment: Either don't upgrade to play 2.0 or wait for 2.1. This is a well aware issue, I myself have a browserID plugin ready for Play20. But I can't release it because of the routing issue.

Comment: Thanks Olivier.  I will be waiting for the release of play2.1